# How to retrieve product add to cart url in phtml file

Tags: magento2, template, addtocart, phtml

I'm looking to add 5 products add to cart buttons to a CMS page in Magento 2, the code example I found online is:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$listBlock = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct');
$addToCartUrl =  $listBlock->getAddToCartUrl($product);
```

Where `$product` is an ID passed to the phtml file from my CMS page, however the above code seems to just gives a white screen and I don't get anything logged in my system or exception files that indicates what's happening.

How would I retrieve the product's add to cart URL in a phtml file from the product ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$productHelper = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
$_product = $productHelper->load($product)

$listBlock = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct');
$addToCartUrl =  $listBlock->getAddToCartUrl($_product);
```

Comment: This works in so far as I get the url - but doesn't add anything to the cart. Do I need to add the form key?

Comment: How would I add that to this url?

Comment: I'm not using a hidden field but a direct URL, so how would that work?

Comment: @Aravona after url you can use :  $URL.'/qty/1/form_key/'.$block->getFormKey()

Comment: Yes but how do I get said formkey?

Comment: @Aravona , Have you got the solution with my updated comment ?

Comment: No unfortunately that didn't work but I changed my thought process and instead of echoing just a url I used your code with a small form. Works fine.