# How to update mini cart on mobile after custom add to cart form submits

Tags: magento2, template, phtml, mini-cart

Following my question [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/143986/40984) I have an issue where my form doesn't update the basket but only on mobile devices. How can I trigger from my phtml file that Magento needs to update the mini cart?

The gifts.phtml file I've created looks like:

```
<?php

$product_id = $block->getData('product');

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$productHelper = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
$_product = $productHelper->load($product_id);

$listBlock = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct');
$addToCartUrl =  $listBlock->getAddToCartUrl($_product);


?>

<form action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $addToCartUrl ?>" method="post"
  id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if ($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
<input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="selected_configurable_option" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
<?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('form_top'); ?>
<?php if (!$block->hasOptions()):?>
    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product_info_form_content'); ?>
<?php else:?>
    <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $block->getOptionsContainer() == 'container1'):?>
        <?php echo $block->getChildChildHtml('options_container') ?>
    <?php endif;?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $block->hasOptions() && $block->getOptionsContainer() == 'container2'):?>
    <?php echo $block->getChildChildHtml('options_container') ?>
<?php endif;?>
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('form_bottom'); ?>
<button type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="btn redButton">
    <span>Add to Cart</span>
</button>

<a href="#" data-post='<?php  echo $this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data')->getAddParams($_product) ?>' class="action towishlist gift-wish" data-action="add-to-wishlist">
    <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#bc0120;font-size: 20px; margin-top:1"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by having the following script

```
<script>
require([
    'jquery',
    'mage/mage',
    'Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation',
    'Magento_Catalog/js/catalog-add-to-cart'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    $('#product_addtocart_form').mage('validation', {
        radioCheckboxClosest: '.nested',
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            var widget = $(form).catalogAddToCart({
                bindSubmit: false
            });

            widget.catalogAddToCart('submitForm', $(form));

            return false;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Which then allowed the mobile mini-cart to update via ajax.